# How to create item parcels for a factor that is not unidimensional?

Tags: spss, factor-analysis, composite

This is follow-up question by ["How to create item parcels in SPSS Amos?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/100123/3277)
My question is how to create item parcels for a factor that is not a unidimensional.
Several articles have mentioned that conducting item parceling only when the factor is unidimensional. I ran the EFA and found that the factor is three-dimensional.Total number of items are 10. Primary purpose of conducting item parceling is to make the parsimonious model. So, if unidimensional is necessary, I might need to find other way to make model more simple.

Comment: Please define or describe `not unidimensional factor`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I might better to write in limitation part.